# Fetch JSON from a url and print onto page

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dom

I am trying to fetch JSON data from a url and display. Using my code below, it does not appear due to uncaught reference error. How can I adjust my code so the data is shown.

```js
var url = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/entry/1258872/";


req.open("GET", url);
req.send();

req.addEventListener("load", function(){
 if(req.status == 200 && req.readyState == 4){
   var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    document.getElementById("id").textContent = response.title;
    document.getElementById("player first name").textContent = response.player_first_name;
     document.getElementById("player last name").textContent = response.player_last_name;
  }
})
```

```html
<h1>Fantasy Premier League</h1>
<h2 id="id"></h2>
<h3>First Name: <span id="player first name"></span></h3>
<h3>Last Name: <span id="player last name"></span></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should define your request `req` object before you call `open` method

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

in your case `req` is undefined and calling method on undefined object will throw an error

a better version of your code will be

```
var url = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/entry/1258872/";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onreadystatechange =  function() {
    if(req.status == 200 && req.readyState == 4){
         var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
         document.getElementById("id").innerText = response.title;
         document.getElementById("player first name").innerText = response.player_first_name;
         document.getElementById("player last name").innerText = response.player_last_name;
  }
};

req.open("GET", url);
req.send();
```

Comment: Also, make sure to allow **Cross origin resource sharing (CORS)** when requesting from another domain.

Comment: Thank you Ali, but while that does fix the first console error, it does not print the JSON information onto the page.

Comment: I think you need to change `textContent` to `innerText` , checkout the edit

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare the XMLHttpRequest object. Buy anyways, it won't return a response from the api due to it's cors policy.

```js
var url = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/entry/1258872/";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url);
req.send();

req.addEventListener("load", function(){
 if(req.status == 200 && req.readyState == 4){
   var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    document.getElementById("id").textContent = response.title;
    document.getElementById("player first name").textContent = response.player_first_name;
     document.getElementById("player last name").textContent = response.player_last_name;
  }
})
```

```html
<h1>Fantasy Premier League</h1>
<h2 id="id"></h2>
<h3>First Name: <span id="player first name"></span></h3>
<h3>Last Name: <span id="player last name"></span></h3>
```

You may make the request using server side as an intermediary, so you can bypass cors policy and access the data. Example in php:

```
$contents = 
file_get_contents("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/entry/1258872/");
echo $contents;
```